How to prevent IP conflicts on a portable Linux box with multiple network interfaces?
The setup
I have a box with two computers inside (Main and Secondary), both running linux (debian based). The Main has three network interfaces. One is for a wireless connection and the others are for ethernet. There are two running services on the Main (Service A and Service B). These services communicate with each other via http. Service A accepts incoming connections on port 80. Service B communicates only with Service A and Service C on the secondary. The Main also serves as an access point.
Currently, the Secondary has a static IP which Service B uses to connect to Service C. The Main's interface 1 can be configured to use static IP or to use DHCP. This is decided by a user. Interface 2 has a static IP which is on the same network as IP of the Secondary. WLAN is fixed to 192.168.30.0/24. Interface 2 and WLAN use different network so there are no collisions.
Box setup
The problem
The box is meant to move frequently from place to place. That means that the LAN will be changing frequently too. A situation might arise when the LAN will collide with either static IP of interface 2 or WLAN. In either situation the linux kernel would not know which interface to use for sending packets (the network would be the same for two interfaces) and that would result in the services not working properly.
Ideal solution
My preferred solution would be to set the Main's interface 2, WLAN and the Secondary once and in a way that would work in any LAN, so that there would not be any collisions. I guess there would need to be some kind of hiding the interface 2.
I have tried to use Linux network namespace. I have added the interface 2 to a namespace and run Service B under this namespace. It almost did what I needed. The issue was that Service A and Service B could not establish a connection with each other.
I have no idea how to prevent a collision between WLAN and interface 1. The only solution that I could come up with is to open the WLAN settings to the user and let him prevent the collision (if the LAN network was in collision, the user would change WLAN settings). But then there needs to be a way to prevent a collision between interface 2 and WLAN.
Is there a way of doing something like this?

That's what link-local addresses are for - they're only valid on a specific link and cannot be routed.
Select random addresses from 169.254.0.0/16 (from RFC 3927) and configure accordingly. Of course, you could use IPv6 addresses from fe80::/64 just as well (RFC 4291).

Yes, this looks exactly like what I need for the interface 2 and LAN collision. Thank you so much. Is there something I can do to prevent a collision with the Access point WLAN and LAN?
